# How to determine how much time a command takes to finish?

Tags: command-line, openssl

I am writing a shell script in `abc.sh`

```
echo $(date)
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.zip -out abc.zip.enc 
echo $(date)
```

It is showing the time at both start and end of the process, but I want the exact amount of time taken to complete such process.

Comment: What do you mean with *original time only for encryption* ?

Comment: yes original time only for encryption  @M.Becerra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `time` command before your command:

```
time command
```

What does it do?

> time (1)             - run programs and summarize system resource usage

For your situation:

```
time openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in abc.zip -out abc.zip.enc
```

It will output something like:

```
real    0m2.199s
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.008s
```

The time in `user` section is what you are looking for, the time that user space worked on your process.

The `sys` is related to kernel and the `real` is what you are getting right now with your `echo` solution, your clock time from running to the end with the time you spend for entering the password.

Comment: When I try to execute the time before opnessl  is mismatching with time displayed with date , then how to do ?

Comment: @prasanna How do you define `mismatching`? Can you provide an example of the values you get?

Comment: @prasanna Yeah, as phihag said provide what are you getting as output in both commands so we can see what is going on.

Comment: i got correct answer i confused sorry friends